# Bot framework embedded WebChat conversationUpdate is not being triggered and iframe token not refreshed

Tags: botframework

I am facing two issues with my embedded web chat.

1. I follow this guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/channel-connect-webchat) I add the iframe and i use the t parameter to use a token. In the documentation it is being mentioned that "Tokens will automatically be renewed before they expire." How are they being renewed? I tried this and after a while the bot disconnects and errors. To solve this i did a C# api controller that gets called from js and this is then being added to the src of the iframe.
2. Seems like ConversationUpdate is not being triggered at all with the web chat. But it works just fine at the emulator and skype.

Comment: For the 2nd point, it's triggering, but only one (not 2 like in the emulator) and once the user has typed something

Comment: Hi @NicolasR I was expecting to trigger that event when the connection is established like the emulator, not when the user types. I wanted to display a greeting message when the connection is established.

Comment: I know, same problem for everyone sadly. One thing that you can do is customize the webchat js/CSS to get a welcome header

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the `ConversationUpdate` is called in **embedded webchat**

here's relevant code I'm using:

```
else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
{
    if (message.MembersAdded[0].Name == @"YourBotName")
    {
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
        await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(message.CreateReply("Hi, this is welcome message"));
    }
}
```